# ¿Por qué me aparece el error 'Error In the XML document (0, 0).' Inner exception?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms

Tengo un error en mi código, quiero deserializar diferentes archivos XML y abrirlos en textbox, el problema que tuve fue cuando tomó la ruta del archivo, creo que es donde está el error, porque se necesita uno ruta de archivo exacta (por ejemplo):

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream ("ejemplo.analy", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Pero lo reemplacé con esto:

FileStream FS = nuevo FileStream (openFileDialog1.FileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Para leer los archivos que se seleccionaron en `openfiledialog`.

Este es mi código completo:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (File.Exists (openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        if ((openFileDialog1.OpenFile ())! = null)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.FileName! = null)
            {
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Analytica Files | * .analy";
                XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reminders.Information));
                FileStream FS = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                Information Info = (information)XS.Deserialize();
                Settings.Default.Counter++;
                Settings.Default.Save();
```

El problema es que cuando intento abrir un archivo, aparece el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error In the XML document  (0, 0).'
>   Inner exception
>   XmlException: Root element Is missing.

Este es el XML en cuestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Information xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">; 
    <Title1>My age has never made me wise</Title1> <Description2>Description</Description2> 
    <Date3>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Date3>
    <Hour4>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Hour4>
</Information>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar el contenido del archivo `xml`? El problema viene dado en que no es un `xml` válido.

Comment: @SebGM2018, agrega el archivo XML ya que el error radica alli.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra El código es: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Title1>My age has never made me wise</Title1>
  <Description2>Description</Description2>
  <Date3>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Date3>
  <Hour4>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Hour4>
</Information>

Comment: @Einer Ya lo he colocado :)

Comment: Los errores que puedo ver son los puntos y comas que no deberian de estar. Si los elimino me carga perfectamente. Verifica que el archivo que estas leyendo tenga contenido.

Comment: @Einer ¿Dónde encontraste los puntos?, ¿Entonces quieres decir que el error está al guardar el archivo?

Comment: Si notas veras un punto y coma al final del primer tag `001/XMLSchema">; `. por lo que si, probablemente sea el guardar que esta mal.

Comment: Mmmm entonces déjame checar mi código y te aviso